# Can I regard the grayscale of a RGB color image as a panchromatic image?

Tags: geology, geography, remote-sensing, software

Here I have a remote sensing dataset with many bands (e.g., blue, green, red, ...), and I use the blue, green and red bands to get a true color image. I want to know if I can get a panchromatic band based on this true color image?

I guess it can be done by displaying the true color image as a grayscale image, then this grayscale image can be seen as a panchromatic image. Or I can convert the RGB format image to HIS format, then the insensity component can be seen as the panchromatic image. I am not sure whether it is right.

Comment: Here several commonly-used methods were introduced to convert RGB to grayscale, such as the averaging and weighing methods: [link] (https://www.dynamsoft.com/blog/insights/image-processing/image-processing-101-color-space-conversion/). We can see that the averaging method is the same as that the intensity component was obtained in converting RGB to HIS.

Comment: Am by far not an expert, but I'd throw in that it may depend an what you're after. If it's just a b/w for a presentation then yes, you can combine and convert them and tell people which channels the result was made of. If you're trying to raise the resolution/detail with that then no, that can't be achieved by this. There's a plethora of conversions between colour spaces, you can even invent your own with some lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

The workflow of fusing RGB true color image and panchromatic grayscale image can help understand this question. After converting RGB color space to the IHS space, the intensity component is replaced with the (high-resolutional) panchromatic image, and then the new intensity, hue, saturation combination as IHS are converted back to the original RGB space.